# DataTemplate not found in merged ResourceDictionary

Tags: xaml, datatemplate, win-universal-app, resourcedictionary

I'm currently developing a universal app for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1.
I share most of my code, but I'm willing to keep style resources appart.

Some context : First, right now I've only started the WP8.1 projects so everything is related to this platform.  In this WP8.1 project, I have a `MainPage.xaml` which contains a `Pivot` control. One of the `PivotItem` is a `UserControl` called, for clarity purposes, `MyUserControl`.

I created a resource dictionary `Styles.xaml` into my "Assets" directory, in BOTH platform projects. Then, I registered those 2 new files into my shared `App.xaml` like this :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="ResourceDictionary">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assets/Styles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In the WP8.1 project `Styles.xaml` file, I created a `DataTemplate` :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="This is a textblock" />
</DataTemplate>
```

In `MyUserControl`, I've added a `ListView` and bound it on the `ItemTemplate` property to `MyDataTemplate` like this :

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyContent}" />
```

When I run the solution and I end up with this error :

```
Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key "MyDataTemplate"
```

**Does anyone know why I encounter this error ? What did I do wrong ?**

An odd thing : when I right click > "Go To Definition" on the `MyDataTemplate` bound in the `ListView.ItemTemplate` property, it routes me to the right place.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong, here is the correct one

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assets/Styles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```